# Error invoking Method 'addUser': Method not found [404] when running addUser function

Tags: meteor

I am quite new to Meteor and I am trying to remove the insecure app.  I have getting the above message.  I have stripped down my code to the most basic.  The function seems to run because I get console.log output (both hello's), but I still get the message and any changes I try to make to the database do not work.

My event code is:

```
Template.body.events({
  'submit .new-user': function(event){
     console.log("hello");
     Meteor.call("addUser");
  }
)};
```

The call...

```
Meteor.methods({
  addUser: function(){
    console.log("Hello");
  }
});
```

Comment: Your `Meteor.methods` code needs to run on the server too

Answer (score 1):

Put your methods in the server folder.

If you leave the methods in any other place, the insecurity still persists.

Meteor has a convention where any code that’s placed within a folder named “server” will only run on the server. This is where we’d place the project’s methods, and the Meteor.publish statement.
from [Tips on structuring meteor apps](http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/structure/)

Comment: Thank you very much.  That makes complete sense now I think about it.  I tried it and it works...well if I put it after the Meteor.IsClient(){}.  Thank you for your help!